# Calculation of variance beta hat

Tags: variance, linear-regression

I have a regression setting of 1 covariate where 
$\sigma^2= 4$ and
$$(X^TX)^{-1} = 
    \begin{pmatrix}
    0.2 & 0.05  \\
    0.05 & 0.14  \\
     \end{pmatrix}
$$
How can I get $Var(\hat{\beta_1})$ and $Var(\hat{\beta_0} - 0.5 \hat{\beta_1})$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need for this problem is that in the standard homoskedastic error setting, the covariance matrix of $\hat\beta = (\hat\beta_0, \hat\beta_1)$ is given by
$$\mathsf{Cov}(\hat\beta) = \begin{pmatrix} \mathsf{Var}(\hat\beta_0) & \mathsf{Cov}(\hat\beta_0, \hat\beta_1) \\ \mathsf{Cov}(\hat\beta_0, \hat\beta_1) & \mathsf{Var}(\hat\beta_1)  \end{pmatrix} = \sigma^2 (X^\top X)^{-1}.$$
You can directly read off $\mathsf{Var}(\hat\beta_1)$; for the latter, use 
\begin{align*}
\mathsf{Var}(\hat\beta_0 - 0.5\hat\beta_1)
&= \mathsf{Var}(\hat\beta_0) + 0.5^2 \mathsf{Var}(\hat\beta_1) - 2\cdot 0.5 \mathsf{Cov}(\hat\beta_0, \hat\beta_1) \\
&= \mathsf{Var}(\hat\beta_0) + 0.25\mathsf{Var}(\hat\beta_1) - \mathsf{Cov}(\hat\beta_0, \hat\beta_1).
\end{align*}